# Google Search engine API

Tags: html, json, computer-science, google-search-api, visual-web-developer

The site should also allow the entry of a search term in a search box, pass that to the Google search engine API.
Google will provide results in JSON format, which should be read and displayed as they were when
reading directly from a JSON file.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Confused on how to start, the documentation on https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview did not help me and I am still confused.